# Customizing *ngIf structural directive to show body of panel clicked and remove bodies of other panels

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive, angular-ng-if

I created a panel which I want to make a re-usable component. I want to make the body of each panel unique to the given panel. This is my re-usable panel code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" (click)="openPanelBody($index)">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-{{arrowDirection}} chevronIcon"></span>
        <h3 class="panel-title"> {{ header }} </h3>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body" *ngIf="opened">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>

</div>
```

The following is my .ts file associated with it:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'panel',
  templateUrl: 'panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})

export class PanelComponent {

    arrowDirection: string = 'right';
    opened: boolean = false;

    openPanelBody($index) {
        this.opened = !this.opened;
        if (this.opened) {
            this.arrowDirection = 'down';
        } else {
            this.arrowDirection = 'right';
        }
    }
}
```

I, then, have a view where I have multiple panels on one page.

```
<div>
    <panel header = "First"></panel>

    <panel header = "Second"></panel>

    <panel header = "Third"></panel>

    <panel header = "Fourth"></panel>

    <panel header = "Fifth"></panel>
</div>
```

I want the body of the first panel to be showing automatically and every time I click on another panel, I want all the bodies of the rest of the panels to collapse/remove from DOM, while opening the body of the panel clicked on. I am having difficulty thinking of a solution for toggling values for the panels. Do I have to create a custom directive that might help with this? Any help to guide me will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: FYI, what you describe is known as an "accordion". See https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples for an example, an Angular API, and example code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a boolean `opened` on your component, use a string property such as `openedPanel`. Then set it to a different string such as `'firstPanel'`, `'secondPanel'`, etc corresponding to the panel that should be open. In your `*ngIf` just check for the appropriate value: `*ngIf="openedPanel == 'secondPanel'`. Now the `*ngIf` will evaluate to true for only one panel at a time and the others will be 'closed'.

Comment: JC, 

I'm slightly confused on the *ngIf check part. Does that mean, I will have a different *ngIf check written for each panel? Because currently my *ngIf is written only once for the "panel" component and I re-used that. How do I set it the values/strings of others?

Comment: Give your panel component an `@Import() name` property and set it in the parent component's template.